# Instantiating a Prefab returns the NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using a `namespace` to instantiate a `prefab` in my game however unity thinks that the `prefab` is not a `GameObject` and returns the `NullReferenceException` error

I've linked the Prefab, properly in the GameObject that holds the script. This is the code that I currently have in Visual Studio but I also tried various forms of the code, they are what follows the first lines of code

```
public GameObject Prefab;
public void OnAppear(){
GameObject spawn = Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation);
spawn.transform.parent = Spawnpoint.transform;}
```

V1
    `var spawn = Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation);`

V2
    `var spawn = Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation) as GameObject;`

**Entire script:**

```
namespace AugReal
{
    public class StartAll : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform Spawnpoint;
        public GameObject Prefab;

        public void OnAppear()
        {
            GameObject spawn = Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation);
            spawn.transform.parent = Spawnpoint.transform;
        }

        public void OnDisappear()
        {
            Debug.Log("You lose");
        }
    }
}
```

**Inspector:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "namespace to instantiate a prefab"?

Comment: This should work, can you provide the console output of the error?

Comment: @dim8 , all of the code that I've provided is inside a namespace. @Musaka Here's what unity returns to me:
`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
AugReal.StartAll.OnAppear () (at Assets/Script/StartAll.cs:15)`

Comment: Whenever I double click that error, it always highlights this code:
`GameObject spawn = Instantiate(Prefab, Spawnpoint.position, Spawnpoint.rotation);`

Comment: Can you show where you are defining SpawnPoint? I suspect that is what is not defined.

Comment: Maybe it's the Spawnpoint the error is telling you about

Comment: `public Transform Spawnpoint;' Should I create this as GameObject instead?

Comment: Show your entire script. That may be more helpful.

Comment: I've edited my post to show the entire code in the script that I'm having a problem with

Comment: As @ErikOverflow commented before, the problem seems to be the SpawnPoint object which may not be initialized. Are you linking any object to it in the Unity editor? (doesn't matter if it is a GameObject or Transform)

Comment: Yeah, I'm linking a GameObject to it

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the inspector for the object you have this code attached to?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/Gj8j3Lb) is the Inspector View

Comment: Maybe your spawnPoint object gets deleted from where it's linked, check if it's there when you execute the OnAppear

Comment: I checked but no, it doesn't get deleted. Also, the GameObject I use for `Spawnpoint` is also the GameObject that contains the script for the `namespace`

Comment: @FrancisAaronMilano If you assign a simple cube to it, does the error persist?

Comment: @Menyus The error still does persist

Comment: Please first [DEBUG your Code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) then you will see **which** of the values is `null`. Then you can further investigate **why**. My guess would be that one of these objects gets destroyed on runtime (e.g. also possible by a scene switch) before it comes to `OnAppear`. Unity doesn't simply lie and clame there is `NullReferenceException` if there isn't...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code instead:

1. You do not need to create a public reference to the transform that this script is attached to. Since the script is a monobehaviour, you can directly access this via *this.transform*
2. Rather than setting the parent explicitly after instantiating, consider usign the Instantiate method with the parent override.

(I have also change the casing on your property "Prefab". It doesn't affect the code, but standard is to keep property names camelCase to distinguish them from the PascalCased class types.)

```
namespace AugReal
{
    public class StartAll : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject prefab;

        public void OnAppear()
        {
            GameObject spawn = Instantiate(prefab, this.transform);
        }

        public void OnDisappear()
        {
            Debug.Log("You lose");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is still being returned by Unity even with the new code. This is the error:
`NullReferenceException
AugReal.StartAll.OnAppear () (at Assets/Script/StartAll.cs:15)
ZZZZTest+<Tests>d__1.MoveNext () (at Assets/Script/ZZZZTest.cs:19)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)`

Comment: Maybe, it's the way I call the `namespace`'s function?

Comment: You know what? You're 100% right. Show your code where you're calling the function?

Comment: @FrancisAaronMilano can you share your code that calls the StartAll.OnAppear method?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I used this code to call the function. I also already changed my code to just call a normal function from a normal class instead of using a namespace to call one.

            `StartAll summall = new StartAll();
            summall.OnAppear();`